# Input capacitor on audio MAX49XX

Tags: audio, filter

I'm trying to design an audio mux based on a [MAX49XX](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/MAX4908.html)

There is input capacitor on audio lines but not any tip to find the value and technology. I suppose that's a high pass filter to block DC signal but how should I compute the value?

I read that ceramic capacitors are not recommended for audio purpose, what type of (small) capacitor can I use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with those devices but reading the datasheet suggests that the capacitors are only required if the previous stage has a DC offset.

The MAX49XX is unusual in that with only a positive supply it will pass an audio signal with voltages above Vcc - 5.5. That means that if you supply it with 3.3 V it can pass signals from 3.3 - 5.5 = -2.2 V to +3.3 V. If your audio signal is within that range then no capacitors are required.

If you do need DC blocking then you select a cut off frequency well below the lowest required audio frequency. The capacitor value is given by $$ C = \frac {1}{2 \pi R f} $$ where *R* is the load resistor (headphones?) and *f* is the cut-off frequency.

If your load is low impedance then you're probably going to need to use an electrolytic capacitor due to the high value capacitor required.